# default free stack space for C - finding safe maximum

Tags: c, memory, stack, stack-overflow

I'm just curious as to how much stack space I can use in my C program.

But in order for me to know that and to create something OS independent, I want to know the default stack space users generally have available for their programs so I don't over-allocate.

Currently I allocated a char array of about 1 MB in size via:

```
char item[1000000];
```

I believe linux can reserve a default stack space of size up to 8 MB. On my computer, I set it to 20 MB. I'm not sure what the default stack space size is in windows.

So my question then is what's the highest safe amount of stack space I can reserve in my program before handing it off to another computer newer than mine only to find the program breaking because it ran out of stack space?

Comment: I wouldn't be so worried about *newer* computers having less memory.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to allocate from the heap using `malloc`? Thread stacks on any OS have limited size for practical reasons and they are not designed for large allocations. Also are you developing a reusable library or an application? The main executable of the application determines the max stack size.

Comment: @iharob 8192 bytes is 8 KB, not 8 MB.

Comment: I also use malloc too but using heap is slower than using stack. and I'd rather use stack to store values temporarily for a very short period of time.

Comment: @Mike I agree with you, it is faster, but will this program be time consuming? Generally the average 32bit windows machine has a default stack size of around 2 megabytes = 8MB.

Comment: @Mike But it's just asking for trouble to try and push the stack to the limit. At best the code will be fragile and prone to breakage as it is changed/added to. Not to mention trying to do that across machines and OS's. Is your application really so high performance that you think using the stack vs the heap is going to make a significant difference? In most cases, tuning the main algorithms in your application is going to buy you much more than fringe optimisations like you are contemplating.

Comment: @mike: the cost of allocating a megabyte is trivial in comparison to anything you might do which uses that megabyte. It may be worth avoiding a million mallocs of 20 bytes, but avoiding 20 mallocs of a million bytes is pointless.